# Load reduction by linking shiny and sql

Tags: r, shiny

I am not good at English, so sentences may be wrong.
I am making a system to narrow down search items with sql.

#### ui.R

```
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    actionButton("clear", "clear"),
    uiOutput("search1_ui"),
    uiOutput("search2_ui"),
    uiOutput("search3_ui"),
    actionButton("go", "go"),
    tableOutput("table")
  )
)
```

#### server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  output$search1_ui <- renderUI({
    sql <- "SELECT DISTINCT CountryCode FROM City;"
    query <- sqlInterpolate(pool, sql)
    x <- dbGetQuery(pool, query)
    x <- matrix(as.matrix(x), nrow(x), ncol(x))
    x <- as.vector(t(x))
    x <- append("", x)
    selectInput("search1", "CountryCode", choices = x)
  })

  output$search2_ui <- renderUI({
    sql <- "SELECT DISTINCT District FROM City WHERE CountryCode = ?coun;"
    query <- sqlInterpolate(pool, sql, coun = input$search1)
    x <- dbGetQuery(pool, query)
    x <- matrix(as.matrix(x), nrow(x), ncol(x))
    x <- as.vector(t(x))
    x <- append("", x)
    selectInput("search2", "District", choices = x)
  })

  output$search3_ui <- renderUI({
    sql <- "SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM City WHERE CountryCode = ?coun AND District = ?dist;"
    query <- sqlInterpolate(pool, sql, coun = input$search1, dist = input$search2)
    x <- dbGetQuery(pool, query)
    x <- matrix(as.matrix(x), nrow(x), ncol(x))
    x <- as.vector(t(x))
    x <- append("", x)
    selectInput("search3", "Name", choices = x)
  })

  observeEvent(input$go,{
    output$table <- renderTable({
      sql <- "SELECT * FROM City WHERE CountryCode = ?coun AND District = ?dist AND Name = ?name;"
      query <- sqlInterpolate(pool, sql, coun = isolate(input$search1), dist = isolate(input$search2), name  = isolate(input$search3))
      dbGetQuery(pool, query)
    })
  })

})
```

#### global.R

```
library(shiny)
library(DBI)
library(pool)

pool <- dbPool(
  drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
  dbname = "shinydemo",
  host = "shiny-demo.csa7qlmguqrf.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
  username = "guest",
  password = "guest"
)
```

There are three problems with this system.
1, Because all sql runs at the time of startup, it becomes heavy. Is it possible to operate only sql of "search1" at startup?

2, "search2" operates and displays after "search1" is selected. Can "search3" work and display after "search2" is selected?

3, I want to create a clear button. Is it possible to display only search1 and clear the table data by pressing the clear button?

In production, queries refer to various tables, so you cannot combine queries at once.
Thank you

Comment: You could add an extra item to each `selectInput` and check for it in the next `observeEvent`. For example in the CountryCode input, add "Please select CountryCode" as the default selection. Then in the `renderUI` for `search2_ui`, check for that value and don't perform the SQL if you find it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't know how to reply.「observeEvent((input$search1 != "Please select CountryCode"),{ 」things like this? Does not work well...

Comment: Just `req()` the previous query result in your render*-functions, so they will "wait". Please see [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/req.html).

Comment: It was realized. Thank you both!